# Visual Studio Community 2017 Fresh Install Error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to fresh install Visual Studio Community 2017  edition, and during the installation process, I get the following error: "Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.WMIProvider"
I have installed visual studio on other machines many times before however, this is a first for me. If you encountered the same problem as me please do tell me the course of action to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually delete everything in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community`
and the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder , hope it helps others